# Is there any way to change computer names on SkyDrive?

Tags: windows-live, onedrive

I've wiped my hard drive a few times I have a couple things called "Computer-Name, Computer-Name-1" and it's extremely annoying. I could just uninstall SkyDrive, but I have 19GB of files I don't want to have to download on to three separate machines again.

I've hunted around, and I can't find it. Going to devices.live.com doesn't solve the problem. (That's only for Live Mesh, not SkyDrive). I haven't been able to find anything in Windows Live's settings.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to disconnect the computer from SkyDrive, update the computer name to the desired one and connect the computer back to SkyDrive:

**Step-by-Step:**

1. Access your SkyDrive account from the [web](http://skydrive.live.com);
2. On the left side of the page, under "PCs", click on the computer name that needs to be removed;
3. On the upper part of the page, click on "Disconnect PC from SkyDrive";
4. The computer name used by SkyDrive is automatically picked up from your computer name, which you can change by accessing the computer's properties. Update your computer name at this point:

   Right clicking "My Computer" then select properties.
5. After successfully removing the computer from SkyDrive, and updating the computer name; re-add the computer to your SkyDrive account;

---

[image: Step two and three Screen Shoot]